# batch math command not working

Tags: batch-file

I seem to have hit a road block with trying to get a batch file to subtract a set number from a user entered variable.  I have a command where a user enters an IP address and then delimits it to four separate octets, then I need to subtract 19 from the last octet.  No matter how I set it up all it get back is -19.  I read that set /a doesn't need the % but nothing seems to help

```
echo. Enter IP address of the CSR on the site.
echo. Example: 11.152.34.82
set /p IP="IP Address: "
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%a in ("%IP%") do echo %%a, %%b, %%c, %%d
pause 
set /a z=d - 19
echo. %z%
pause
```

I have also tried

```
set /a z=%%d - 19
echo. %z%
pause
```

and

```
set /a z=%d% - 19
echo. %z%
pause
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use %%varname, but %varname% in.bat file

Comment: You try to acces `%%d` outside from the loop, but there it isn't defined anymore

Comment: You realize you are going to have to do some data validation to make sure that the 4th octet is greater than 19.

Answer (score 4):

Capture the last octet within the loop then operate on that variable:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%a in ("%IP%") do (
    echo %%a, %%b, %%c, %%d
    set last=%%d
)

set /a z=%last% - 19
echo z=%z%
```

Comment: You can also write it as `set /a z=last - 19`

Comment: You could even do the calculation within the `for /F` loop: `set /a z=%%d - 19` (so no need for the interim variable `last`)...

Answer (score 1):

Using the method similar to the last one I provided in you last question:

```
@Echo Off
Echo= Enter IP address of the CSR on the site.
Echo= Example: 11.152.34.82
Set/P "IPA= "
Call :Sub %IPA:.= %

Rem Your commands using new %IPA% here:
Echo= Your new IP address is %IPA%

Pause
Exit/B

:Sub
    ClS
    If %4 Gtr 19 Set/A LO=%4-19
    Set "IPA=%1.%2.%3.%LO%"
```